# how do I read a text file and find a specific value in it?

Tags: matlab

I have a text file that each line of it is as follows:

```
n:1 mse_avg:8.46 mse_y:12.69 mse_u:0.00 mse_v:0.00 psnr_avg:38.86 psnr_y:37.10 psnr_u:inf psnr_v:inf 
n:2 mse_avg:12.20 mse_y:18.30 mse_u:0.00 mse_v:0.00 psnr_avg:37.27 psnr_y:35.51 psnr_u:inf psnr_v:inf 
n:3 mse_avg:10.89 mse_y:16.33 mse_u:0.00 mse_v:0.00 psnr_avg:37.76 psnr_y:36.00 psnr_u:inf psnr_v:inf 
n:4 mse_avg:12.45 mse_y:18.67 mse_u:0.00 mse_v:0.00 psnr_avg:37.18 psnr_y:35.42 psnr_u:inf psnr_v:inf
```

I need to read each line in a separate line and I use `readvars` matlab function, but the output is only `n` as follow

```
n
n
n
n
```

and it cannot extract other variables. do you know what is the problem? does Matlab have any other functions for reading a text file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original question asked about extracting only `n` and `psnr_avg`. I'm not sure if that was edited out accidentally or intentionally.

If that's still the case, try to [textscan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) the lines and then extract `n` and `psnr_avg` with [named regexp tokens](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btqhkwj-7):

```matlab
fid = fopen('data.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);

M = regexp(data{1}, 'n:(?<n>\d+).*psnr_avg:(?<psnr_avg>[^\s]+)', 'names');
```

```
>> M{:}

ans = 

  struct with fields:

           n: '1'
    psnr_avg: '38.86'


ans = 

  struct with fields:

           n: '2'
    psnr_avg: '37.27'


ans = 

  struct with fields:

           n: '3'
    psnr_avg: '37.76'


ans = 

  struct with fields:

           n: '4'
    psnr_avg: '37.18'
```